# artisan tinker: mkdir() permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Laravel Version 5.0.33

```
> php artisan tinker

  [ErrorException]            
  mkdir(): Permission denied
```

This is on a production server, I was trying to test a command with tinker as the web user.  This user owns every directory in the base path, so I'm not sure what directory is attempted to be created when I run artisan tinker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using very verbose `-vvv`, I was able to get a stack trace.

```
Exception trace:
 () at /data1/vhosts/website.com/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:459
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 mkdir() at /data1/vhosts/website.com/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:459
 Psy\Configuration->getHistoryFile() at /data1/vhosts/website.com/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:598
```

getHistoryFile() attempts to create a file in the user home directory, not the application directory.  This user's home was set to /var/www/html but it didn't have execute permissions on that folder.

Comment: @Jebediah make sure you have execute permissions (permission to create files/folders) in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 16):

Place .psysh.php in the root of a Laravel project with this content

```
<?php
return [
        'runtimeDir'    => './.psysh',
    ];
```

More info
https://github.com/laravel/tinker/issues/34#issuecomment-357550126

Comment: If you don't want a .psysh folder hanging around using /tmp seems to work fine also.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs because you switch user (guessing using su) without "dash" option.

Replace su www-data with su - www-data and everything should works!

or

su - username

where username has the ssh login permission

The dash symbol before username is important

reference : [here](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/443#issuecomment-395759749)