# Laravel - "artisan tinker" -> mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-artisan, tinker

I have been searching for hours now but cannot find a solution even though there are similar problems out there.

I am trying to run `php artisan tinker` on a fresh laravel installation with user `webmaster` (who is owner of the project directory `demo`) but I am getting the following error:

```
In Configuration.php line 352:
mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Running with verbose flag:

> Exception trace:
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
>       mkdir() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Configuration.php:352
>       Psy\Configuration->getRuntimeDir() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php:185
>       Psy\Shell->getDefaultCommands() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1211
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:435
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->add() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/psy/psysh/src/Psy/Shell.php:134
>       Psy\Shell->add() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:421
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->addCommands() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/tinker/src/Console/TinkerCommand.php:54
>       Laravel\Tinker\Console\TinkerCommand->handle() at n/a:n/a
>       call_user_func_array() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
>       Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}() at
>   /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/
>   BoundMethod.php:87
>       Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31
>       Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:549
>       Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:183
>       Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:252
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:170
>       Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:938
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:240
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
>       Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:88
>       Illuminate\Console\Application->run() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:121
>       Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /media/usb/drive1/websites/demo/artisan:37

Hope anyone has a hint for me. Thanks!

## Relevant information

- **Distribution**: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
- **Webserver**: Apache/2.4.25
- **Laravel version**: 5.5 (latest)
- **DocumentRoot**: `/var/www/websites -> /media/usb/drive1/websites/`
- **Apache user**: `www-data` (has permissions in project directory)

## Similar reported issues

- https://github.com/laravel/tinker/issues/34
- [artisan tinker: mkdir() permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601260/artisan-tinker-mkdir-permission-denied)

Comment: `DocumentRoot` should be Laravel's `public/` folder, have you set that correctly?

Comment: Right, but I am running a development server with multiple projects to reach over a domain. I don't think this has something to do with this issue anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the runtimeDir in `Configuration->getRuntimeDir()` to find out where the permission is denied?

Comment: @sisve Thanks for your comment! How would I achieve to dump a variable to terminal?

Comment: `dump($variable);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has been a year since I asked the question. I simply ignored the lack of use of tinker and went on. But today I finally found a solution and thought it might be a good idea to share.

The shared server environment might causing this error. Dumping the variable `$this->runtimeDir` on line 352 from file `vendor/psy/psysh/src/Configuration.php` tells me about missing permissions to create a folder in `/run/user/1000/psysh`, where `1000` is the uid.

A workaround is to tell psysh to use a directory where the operating user has write access. This can be done with the `runtimeDir` config option. All you need to do is to create a config file in `~/.config/psysh/config.php` or locally as `.psysh.php` in the project root of Laravel. Add the following content and you are ready to go.

```
<?php
return [
    'runtimeDir' => './.psysh',
];
```